# R - aov() - only do two-way interactions

Tags: r

If I'm running an ANOVA in R using aov(), how do I limit the interaction terms to only two-way interactions? For example, this code:

```
model <- aov(y ~ a * b * c, data=data)
summary(model)
```

will create a model with a, b, c, ab, ac, bc, and abc. How can I limit this so the only interactions that appear in the model are ab, ac, and bc? I've tried

```
aov(y ~ a .*. b .*. c, data = data)
```

but that threw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a formula, the `^` operator limits interaction terms to the specified order:

```
aov(y ~ (a + b + c)^2, ...)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly specify the terms you want to include in your model by

```
model <- aov(y ~ a + b + c + a:b + b:c + a:c, data=data)
```